How to create an animated Bottom Navigation Bar in Jetpack Compose that opens and closes with animation
I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose, and I would like to implement a bottom navigation bar with a menu that opens and closes with smooth animations.
The navigation bar at the bottom should have multiple icons, and when a certain icon is clicked, a menu should appear with an animation (e.g., a fade-in or slide-up animation). The menu should also close with a reverse animation when a close icon is pressed.
The main requirements are:
A bottom navigation bar with multiple items.
A menu that opens with an animation when a specific item is clicked.
The menu should close with an animation when triggered.
What is the best way to achieve this in Jetpack Compose? Should I use AnimatedVisibility, BottomSheetScaffold, or something else?

Thank you for your help!

looks more like a bottom sheet!

The main steps to achieve this behavior are as follows.

Create a simple bottom navigation bar with multiple items.
Manage the currently selected item's state and the animated menu's visibility.
Use AnimatedVisibility to animate the opening and closing of the menu.

Consider this as your menu:
@Composable
fun MenuContent(onClose: () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Menu Item 1")
        Text("Menu Item 2")
        Text("Menu Item 3")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

        Button(onClick = onClose) {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}

And the rest of implementation:
@Composable
fun BottomNavWithMenu() {
    var isMenuVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(BottomNavItem.Home) }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation() {
                BottomNavItem.values().forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = { Icon(item.icon, contentDescription = item.contentDescription) },
                        label = { Text(item.label) },
                        selected = selectedItem == item,
                        onClick = {
                            if (item == BottomNavItem.More) {
                                isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible // Toggle menu visibility
                            } else {
                                selectedItem = item
                                isMenuVisible = false // Close menu if another item is clicked
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) { padding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding).fillMaxSize()) {
            MainContent(selectedItem)

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isMenuVisible,
                enter = fadeIn() + slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
                exit = fadeOut() + slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                MenuContent(onClose = { isMenuVisible = false })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainContent(selectedItem: BottomNavItem) {
    // Your main content based on selectedItem
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(text = "Selected Item: ${selectedItem.label}")
    }
}

enum class BottomNavItem(val label: String, val icon: @Composable () -> Unit, val contentDescription: String) {
    Home("Home", { Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, null) }, "Home"),
    Search("Search", { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, null) }, "Search"),
    More("More", { Icon(Icons.Filled.MoreHoriz, null) }, "More")
}

The main concept is about the navbar item click event and your custom menu's animated visibility.
